# azure function app project - keep getting error that I'm missing parameters file for ARM Template

Tags: azure-functions, azure-resource-manager

I have an azure function app that relies on an ARM Template.
At some point, I started to get an error saying that I'm missing a parameters file... which is true. I don't have one.  But I don't want one.

This is what i see in the IDE:

[image]

Any tips on how to get rid of this error would be appreciated.  From what I can see the resources themselves do get deployed with the right names etc, despite the error

Comment: Honestly, I'd try removing and reinstalling the Visual Studio Code Azure Resource Manager Tool Extension. As long as you have default values for parameters (and it looks like you do), it's a valid template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have tried to reproduce the issue but unable to get the parameter issue which you are getting.

- We are using the same valid template which you are using for Create Azure function and deployed to Azure successfully as well.

[image]

- *To get rid of the issue please try to change the parameter setting to None- if you don't want any parameter file*.

[image]

The ARM tool extension that we are using.

[image]

For more information please refer this ***MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION***:- [***Create and deploy Azure Functions resources from an ARM template***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-function-resource-manager?tabs=visual-studio-code%2Cazure-cli)